# Using Messengers and Binders for Inter Process Communication

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service, messenger

I am facing the following problem.

My Application needs to communicate between 2 Services, 1 for Network, 1 for rudementary Phoneservices.

Now, I did the following to achieve IPC:

I extended the `BinderClass` as normal, and return an own `Binder` in my `onBind()` method. That works just fine. But now I want to have in addition to that the possibility to send Messages between my `Service` and my `Activity`. But here lies the problem. Since I return my own `Binder` in the `onBind()` method like this:

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent){
    Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "BIND");
    return binderToThisProcess;
}
```

I can not return an additional Messenger like this:

```
...
return outMessenger.getBinder();
```

I mean of course this is obvious cause the return statement allows only one Object to be returned.

My Question is: Is there any way I can append the `Messenger` onto my own `Binder`? Or is there a similar way to achieve what I am looking for? Or did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution seems very obvious for me - just write your own class what extends `Binder`. You can add any custom fields or methods to your `CustomBinder` class. Simply instantiate your `CustomBinder` and return it in  `onBind()` method.

Comment: Thats the solution Thank you!